# Sending a PDF file from external storage to Telegram via FileProvider give Error in Android 10

Tags: java, android, pdf, telegram, android-fileprovider

well I can store pdf file in external storage correctly.
but the problem is when I want to send it via fileProvider to telegram it got this error "unsupported attachment" in telegram app.

this is my code to share pdf:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath(), viewModel.getUserData().getCaseNo() + ".pdf");
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(), "com.nsard.provider", file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        intent.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri("", uri))
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, requireContext().getContentResolver().getType(uri));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        Snackbar.make(binding.getRoot(), file.getPath() + "\n" + uri.getPath(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with"));
```

I also try this solution [attachment problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60089599/unsupported-attachment)
but it did not solve.

the point is that in android lower it works correctly but in 10+ face error.

thanks.

Comment: Use file.exists() and file.canRead() before you start the intent.

Comment: You do not have to set clip data.

Comment: You do not have to set a write flag.

Comment: Share with other apps. Does that go ok?

Comment: ??? I have no idea what you did to solve your issue.

Comment: well I use `file.exists()` and also  `file.canRead()` before start the intent

Comment: set clip data and set a write flag was wrong as you mentioned but they did not related to my problem
actually I had added them because of this problem but it was not a right work

Comment: Did you solve your problem meanwhile? And what did you do with exists() and canRead()? You are supposed to comment in them as we have no idea what you do. You said you used them but are they both true? Or what?

Comment: In fact before `startActvity` I use this code `if(file.exist()&& file.canRead())`
and I do not have any idea why it works:)

Answer (score 0):

Post Android 10 file access has changed. Please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66642726/java-io-filenotfoundexception-open-failed-eexist-file-exists-android-11/66645800#66645800).